# jQuery UI datepicker and mobile "wrapper"

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have tried to use mobile "wrapper" for jQuery UI datepicker based on [that page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/)

Working code (part of Wordress template) looks like:

Header:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

part of HTML:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery("#dataStart").datepicker({

        minDate: '+2d',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        onSelect: function(date){
            var dates = date.split('/');
            var lastDate = new Date(dates[2], dates[0], 0);
            var y = lastDate.getFullYear(), m = lastDate.getMonth(), d = lastDate.getDate();
            m = ('0'+ (m+1)).slice(-2);

            jQuery('#dataEnd').val(m+'/'+d+'/'+y);

            var start = jQuery('#dataStart').datepicker('getDate');
            jQuery('#dataEnd').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'}).datepicker('setDate', m+'/'+d+'/'+y);
            var end = jQuery('#dataEnd').datepicker('getDate');
            var days   = ((end - start)/1000/60/60/24)+1;

            jQuery('#calculated').text(days);          
        }
    });
});
</script>
<tr>
<td width="123" height="25" style="text-align: right;"><label for="dataStart">Start Date:</label>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" class="copy11"><input type="text" style="width: 88px;" class="datepicker" id="dataStart" size="10" name="dataStart" data-role="date" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="123" height="25" style="text-align: right;"><label for="dataEnd">End Date:</label>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left" valign="top" class="copy11"><input type="text" style="width: 88px;" class="end_date" id="dataEnd" size="10" name="dataEnd" value="" readonly /></td>
</tr>
```

and when I follow example from provided link above, to have it "mobile friendly", datepicker jQuery UI API is not working as well is not really getting to be "mobile friendly".

Comment: The datepicker (jQM) will only work with jQuery-Mobile.

Comment: "Wrapper", from provided link, is loading `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` not jQM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [jQuery UI Datepicker Monkey Patch](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2014/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-for-jquery-mobile.html) and it works fine "wrapping" regular jQuery UI for mobile devices.